# Filtering an rdd depending upon a list of values in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to apply filter based on a list of values in Spark. This is how I get the list:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("../sample.json");

        df.groupBy("token").count().show();

        Tokens = df.select("token").collect();
        for(int i = 0; i < Tokens.length; i++){
            System.out.println(Tokens[i].get(0)); // Need to apply filter for Token[i].get(0)
        }
```

Rdd on which I want apply filter is this:

```
JavaRDD<String> file = context.textFile(args[0]);
```

I figured out a way to filter in java:

```
private static final Function<String, Boolean> Filter =
            new Function<String, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(String s) {
                    return s.contains("Set");
                }
            };
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not fully understanding your problem. If you have created a list and you want to use that list to filter you file rdd, can you then not simply use the `filter` function?

```
file.filter(str -> list.contains(str))
```